# Adding extra, possibly unneeded, tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

As I understand the main purpose of tags is to categorize content. Some tags target a generic language like SQL, and can (and in many cases should) be qualified with the specific product (and version if applicable) that the question refers to.

Tags also determines the badge progress you can make if gaining points on from an answer and my question is what the policy on adding more tags to a question with the intent of making the question more searchable, as the side effect (which might be desired) is to gain badge progress.

I have a vague memory of reading that fewer tags are better, and I'm not sure I agree with this. Surely using as many as possible of the five tags would increase a questions visibility and possibility to be found in tag limited a search?

Note that I'm not talking about adding dubious tags, but rather tags that should be part of a hierarchy if SO had that design feature (like SQL -> SQL Server -> SQL Server 2012 -> TSQL).

**TL;DR:

Is it ok to add tags when you stand to gain badge progress from doing so?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me like you're describing meta tags or tags that *seem* like meta tags but actually *aren't*.

Take for instance SQL - it's a tag that does have the ability to stand on its own, as there is a formal standard around it.

With SQL Server and SQL Server 2012, I get the strong inclination that one is attempting to hit a more broad audience, but let's be blunt:  using a version-specific tag here isn't necessary **unless** the question specifically has to do with that version of SQL Server.

Then there's the TSQL tag, which is a proprietary extension of SQL.  This mildly conflicts with the SQL tag, but not *a lot*.

So the question is effectively compartmentalized to a question about SQL Server and TSQL.  Why do we need those other tags?  They'd only add more noise.

I'd encourage one to add tags that make sense to their specific problem.  Of course, many people *don't*, but this shouldn't stop one from editing in/narrowing the tags on questions where they don't make much sense.

Comment: I used the SQL (Server) family of tags as those are the ones I frequent the most, but for the sake of discussion it could be say Java + Java7 or Java8 or something similar. Is adding tags to make the question searchable by more tags really noise? I'm not sure I agree. In the SQL example - if the question refers to - and uses features specific to say SQL Server 2012, shouldn't it still be tagged with the unspecific SQL Server tag? I wouldn't think most people search for specific versions?

Comment: **Yes.**  If you're talking about specific versions of Java then it makes sense to add those tags. However, adding all three of them at once is nothing *but* noise since there are new features specific to Java 7 and Java 8.  If it's a generic Java question, the one tag will do.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I'll leave the question open a bit longer to see if anyone else wants to pitch in before I accept as I still am not sure about the ethical aspect of tagging for personal gain :)